# Не работает transition во Vue компоненте

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Имеется следующий код во Vue-компоненте:

```
<template>
   <div>
      <transition name="fade">
         <p v-if="show">Now you see me</p>
      </transition>
   </div>
</template>
```

Свойство `show` определено.
В консоли выдает следующую ошибку:

> Uncaught TypeError: slots[name$1].every is not a function.

Никак не смог понять, с чем она связана.

Comment: Вероятно проблема в javascript коде, так как на [codepen](https://codepen.io/dima74/pen/xpMNoQ) ошибки не возникает

Answer (score 2):

Столкнулся с похожей проблемой, но у меня даже ошибок в консоли не было. 
P.S. проблема решилась добавлением атрибута "key" к анимируемому элементу